# Swift 3 Compiler error: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, compiler-errors

I'm trying to extend a Firebase class but am getting a compiler error with the following:

It appears to be related to the failable initialiser but I'm not sure. Is this a bug?

```
class FIRAuthMock: FIRAuth {
    var mockUser: FIRUser

    init?(user: FIRUser) {
        self.mockUser = user
    }   
}
```

Xcode 8.0, Swift 3.0

Comment: I don't know why the compiler is crashing. But your initializer is illegal. You must call an initializer in `super`.

Comment: @matt Yeah I was thinking that but `super.init()` is unavailable I'm assuming by design... Any way around this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I don't know anything about FIRAuth. I'm just telling you the rules for an initializer in a subclass. You _must_ call a designated initializer in `super`. Now, if FIRAuth itself has an `init(user:)` things are much more involved...

Comment: @matt I think I'm going to have to come up with another plan as `FIRAuth` is a singleton with a private `init`.  Looks like it is a bug though as it should generate an inline error rather than a compiler error no?

Comment: Compiler crashing is always bad and Apple definitely wants to know about it. Feel free to file a bug with bugs.swift.org, but you will have to provide details about FIRAuth.

Comment: @matt Yeah will do. I think I know how to replicate it with my own classes so might not need to involve firebase. Thanks for the help mate!